# Excel: What's an alternative to VLOOKUP that handles repeated lookup values?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, worksheet-function

VLOOKUP *almost* does what I need, but it won’t retrieve all the numbers associated with a list value that’s in the table multiple times. E.g. for table,
A 1
A 2
B
C 1
D 1
D 2

Is there an alternative function to return 1 and 2 for lookup value D? If I had to use a macro, what would it look like?

Comment: What format would multiple values be returned in?

Comment: How many times the value to look for can appears in your list?

Comment: 47 out of 939K rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using a filter fed by a named range?

Comment: This worked! I had ~1M list rows, with 40 lookup values of interest, yielding 46 associated numbers.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to sum the numbers, you could use

```
=SUMIF(A1:A6,"D",B1:B6)
```

to count them

```
=COUNTIF(A1:A6,"D",B1:B6)
```